# How to Register a Type Library without RegAsm.exe

Tags: .net, com-interop, regasm, dllregistration, tlbexp

I want to know if it's possible to register a type library without using the [RegAsm tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6%28VS.80%29.aspx).  Here is my situation, which will hopefully explain why I want to do this:

I'm developing an assembly in .NET that will provide some modern functionality for our older VB6 applications.  I have successfully registered the assembly and the type library on my development machine using RegAsm like so:

```
regasm.exe MyAssembly.dll /tlb /codebase
```

The above command generates the type library (MyAssembly.tlb) and registers it as well as registering the assembly.  I need the type library registered so that I can have Intellisense in VB6.

**My problem with this method**  is that I don't have the same level of control when generating the type library file as I do with [TlbExp.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hfzzah2c%28VS.80%29.aspx).  In particular, I need to use TlbExp's /names flag to [specify the proper case](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/5003c486-ed3f-4ec8-8398-a1251b0f9e74) of my property names (RegAsm butchers them).  So if I use TlbExp to generate my tlb file, is there any way that I can register it separately from the assembly registration process?

**Edit:** da_m_n's answer is correct for the question I asked.  However, I was under the faulty assumption that just because RegAsm could register a type library that it was necessary to register the tlb in order reference it in VB6.  So for now I'm registering the assembly and referencing the unregistered, TlbExp-generated tlb with the fixed names.

Comment: Actually, I think I might be mistaken in the assumption that I must register the tlb file in order to reference it in VB6.  Perhaps this question is for nothing.  I'll look into it tomorrow.

Comment: And now I can't find regtlib.exe on my computer. I can find regtlibv12.exe but no documentation at all. Looks to me like MS is no longer keen on .NET anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use regtlib.exe to register the tlbexp generated tlb file.

Answer (score 2):

`regtlib.exe` is not available on Win10 platforms.  Use the appropriate `TlbExp.exe` as found in the corresponding .NET SDK (e.g. `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools\TlbExp.exe" "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)"`
see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/tlbexp-exe-type-library-exporter).

Comment: Tlbexp.exe generates a type library but does not register it. This is in contrast to the Assembly Registration tool (Regasm.exe), which both generates and registers a type library. To generate and register a type library with COM, use Regasm.exe.

Comment: @EduBic, good insight, ... But on a build machine, where the executables are not run, just packaged, one might only need the type library built.