# Building an COM-interop enabled project without registering it during build

Tags: visual-studio, registry, com-interop, typelib

In Visual Studio 2010, I'm trying to build an COM-interop enabled C# project without registering it during build, but I *DO* require the assembly's typelibrary (.tlb) file, so I can import it from another C++ project in the solution.

I haven't found a way of doing this - there once upon a time was a tlbexp.exe tool, but it was deprecated in favor of regasm.exe /tlb (which unlike tlbexp.exe, registers it).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375585/how-to-register-a-type-library-without-regasm-exe

Comment: @rwong - related, but not at all the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tlbexp is still available in VS2010 here:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\TlbExp.exe
```

Comment: Should be used in a post-build event to answer the need of allowing it to be imported from another project, so that building a solution will work properly.